# passing argument 2 of 'memcpy' discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type

Tags: c, embedded

I have a `volatile char * start_address;` which is pointing to register sections (might change due to hardware behavior). I need to read it and I am using:

```
memcpy (
    result_p,            // starting address of destination
    start_address,       // starting address of source
    result_len           // for the length of the payload
);
```

I am getting this warning:

> passing argument 2 of '`memcpy`' discards '`volatile`' qualifier from
>   pointer target type

Is a safer way to read the sections or a better way to use memcpy and prevent this warning?

Comment: What's a typical value for `result_len`? Are the registers all 8-bits with no gaps in between registers? Personally, using `memcpy` would not be my first choice when dealing with hardware registers. But without more information about the hardware, it's difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Checking: You want to read multiple registers at once?

Comment: How do you synchronise this memory to avoid race conditions? And if you are sure it is synchronised, why not just cast away the volatile modifier?

Comment: In most cases you really don't want to use `volatile`. It is severely underspecified by the standard and it doesn't make things thread safe (although many people seem to believe that), it mostly just serves to inhibit the optimizer from doing clever things with your code. Are you sure you don't actually want an atomic variable?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: This is an embedded project and there is an acnowledged defect in the standard which luckily is not implemented by any implementation. Instead they implement how it is supposed to be. For hardware-registers, `volatile` is the correct qualifier.

Comment: There can only be one scenario where you need to do this, and that is when you are copying a receiver buffer from hardware to RAM, or possibly from a "DMA'd" part of RAM to other RAM. In which case the most important part is to ensure that the copy takes place at a point in time where data integrity can be guaranteed. That is, that you can be sure that part of the data doesn't suddenly change in the middle of the copy.

Comment: @Lundin: I've seen FPGA-implementation which flag such in-between updates safely. They were triggered by reading the first address and if there was a write to any address not read in the cycle, either a flag was set or that address was stored.

Comment: result_len is not fixed (reg section is in an fpga and there are different structures with different length). physical addresses and data_length are being generated by another tool (they are in a header file) the physical address is being mapped on local memory (using mmap). they problem is if I don't use volatile then due to optimization, compile might not read the actual location (which can be modified by RTL at any moment) and this warning worries me because I think the code might not do what I want it to do. (access and read the value every time I call a function)

Comment: yes multiple registers at once (basically data structs with variable width are being mapped on the memory) so result_p is the starting address of a struct which can be 8 bytes long or 64 bytes long or some other length and start_address is the address returned by mmap (mapping the physical address of the register on local memory) and I want to make a copy of the registers and interpret the data.

Comment: BTW thank you guys for responding, I couldn't comment on this earlier because stackoverflow was not able to load its javascript libraries for some reason!

Answer (score 24):

`memcpy` is incompatible with volatile objects, and the mismatched pointer type in the function signature is helping point this out to you. `memcpy` may copy in any order, in any unit size, read parts of the source multiple times, write parts of the destination multiple times, etc. On the other hand, `volatile` expresses an intent that the sequence and number of accesses to the object must be exactly what they would be in the abstract machine. If you want to copy `volatile` arrays, you need to write your own copy loop that looks like a naive `memcpy`, and use the right `volatile` type for the pointer in your loop.

Comment: This doesn't avoid race conditions in the code by itself. You can read an integer atomically, but you can't copy an array atomically. If the array changes during the loop, it doesn't really matter if you read it back to front or front to back. You still end up with corrupt data.

Comment: @jforberg depends of what is corrupt data in each case. You might not care that data changes while reading, but do care that each register is read once and just once. Depends on the hw implementation and on the meaning of the registers.

Comment: @jforberg: Race conditions are outside the scope of the question. A volatile object is allowed to (and will, for various hardware) produce a different result/behavior each time you read it; this is implementation-defined. But that's not the reason you can't use `memcpy`.

Comment: @atturri OK, that makes more sense. It seems I did misread the question. I see in the source for glibc that it can actually copy whole VM pages sometimes if the OS supports it. Which would probably not work terribly well if the VM page refers to memory mapped hardware.

Comment: @jforberg: The question is about hardware peripheral registers. This is a completely different beast than concurrent code execution by the CPU(s). For instance, such regions are typically strictly ordered/non-cachable.

Comment: SO you mean just to have a loop that iterates for the number of struct's bytes and then a pointer to a volatile uint8_t  . . . and then I just set my variable equal to the value of the pointer within the loop, right?!

Comment: @Hani_l: Well that's only valid if the MMIO registers or whatever the underlying volatile object is can safely be accessed as bytes (but in that case it should generally work). I've worked with hardware where byte IO either does nothing or horribly misbehaves, and 32-bit word IO is needed to work properly. So you really need to write a function that's appropriate to whatever you're accessing.

Answer (score 14):

General advice is not to use `memcpy` for hardware peripheral registers or `volatile` qualified objects in general, even **iff** they occupy a gap-less memory region. They typically need a specific access pattern `memcpy` does not guarantee. This includes using optimised wider transfers, accessing the same location multiple times or changing the order of accesses.

For the reasons above and the following, don't even think about casting away the `volatile` qualifier! The compiler might very well optimize the call away (e.g. if you have two identical calls without changes to source nor destination area in-between), combine two accesses or move the call before/after other hardware accesses.

Instead write your own copy function/loop keeping the qualifier. That will force the compiler to generate code which exactly does what you want. Remember to use the correct type for the copy pointers. Note also that the standard integer types are not a good choice for hardware registers of a specific size. Use the fixed-width types from `stdint.h` like `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, ... instead.

Comment: "if you copy the same source to the same destination"  This isn't allowed by memcpy, the parameters are `restrict` pointers. You'll have to use `memmove` for that.

Comment: @Lundin: Sorry, that was badly worded. I hope the edit make more clear what I actually meant.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, you could use `std::copy`. It will take any type of (input) iterator, and a *pointer to* `volatile` is a perfectly valid input iterator.

Comment: it is written all in C (C++ tag was added by stack-overflow suggestions, I am not even sure when!)