# memcpy from array to area of memory

Tags: c, memory

I am working on a small embedded device, where to draw graphics to the screen, you need to write bytes to an area of vram and then flush it to the display.

If I have an image of the same size as the screen, in standard c array form, would the correct way to copy the image be:

```
memcpy(vram_base, image, LCD_HEIGHT_PX*LCD_WIDTH_PX*3) //3 bytes for 24-bit colour
```

where vram_base is the non-changing start point of the area that can be flushed to the lcd
and image is of the form

```
char img[] = {0x00, 0xd6, 0x3a, ...}
```

If that's not the right, what would be the right way in c?

Comment: Assuming the data in the array is in the right format and contains the amount of data you're copying then why do you think it might not be correct? Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: It is "not right" only in a bit exotic way. Since the `vram_base` is not something the C abstract machine is aware of producing side effects, it should be defined as `volatile`. But `memcpy` does not take `volatile` as an argument and will discard this qualifier. So *theoretically* this call might get optimized out. In most cases, in practice, it won't. But nothing in the standard will guarantee it.

Comment: An extended explanation on what @EugeneSh. is saying can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729240/passing-argument-2-of-memcpy-discards-volatile-qualifier-from-pointer-target

Comment: The reason i'm not sure it might be right is that when I use memcpy, as opposed to a loop through each byte of the image and poke-ing it to vram, I get a compiler error saying I have overflowed the available system ram by 100kb. I have absolutely no idea why a memcpy based solution would use so much more ram.

Comment: This is not really what you are asking. There might be many reasons for your problem, but it would require a separate question to cover these (and more details about your code, environment and build process)